# Merge modules (msm) for Microsoft Access Data base engine

Tags: merge-module

My code needs Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" package for working correctly.

However the code is packaged in an MSI hence, we need to package the Access Database Engine 2010 (exe) also with in an MSI. But the question is, is it possible to get merge modules (msm) for Access Data Base engine as well?

Comment: did you get solution to achieve this? if yes then please share. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The merge module for access database engine is supposed to exist.
try http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/msm.htm which has the below info.

> Microsoft Jet Jet 3.5 InstallShield Developer includes a merge module
>   that installs Jet 3.51. It was written by InstallShield Software
>   Corporation.
>
> Below is a user created MSJET35.msm that installs the Microsoft Jet
>   3.5 core files and some ISAM (not Exchange driver).
>
> Update: Removed incorrect entries from Registry table
>
> ZIP MSJET35.zip    Written by Heath Stewart File size: 1.953.262 bytes
>   Last update: 2004-09-13
>
> Jet 4.0 InstallShield Developer includes a merge module that installs
>   Jet 4.0 SP6. It was written by InstallShield Software Corporation. It
>   is also available for download from the InstallShield web site.

Alternatively, you can write your own msm which microsoft tells you how to do:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/authoring-merge-modules